# Rendering failed with a known bug FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

Hi i'm getting this rendering error from the layout editor.

[image]

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FloatingActionButton_backgroundTint
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:164)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:153)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:262)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:220)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="categoryHandler"
        type="ci.ali.moneymaker.handlers.CategoryHandler" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/background_grey"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="@{categoryHandler::addCategory}"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:rippleColor="#99FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

What i've tried so far:
1. grandle dependencies on the same version

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.4'
compile 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.7'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
}
```

2. removed backgroundTint from FAB.
3. changed dependencies versions.
4. invalidate Caches / Restart
5. Recreated FAB
6. Created a new project and added FAB to new Layout. Everything worked fine.

Nothing worked so far. Hope you can help me to resolve the error.

If i open the FloatingActionButton.java class, there are some import errors as shown in the Screenshot. [image]

Maybe this cause the error. But i still don't know how to resolve.

Comment: code where you call the FAB Button? Also, possible solution would be changing the `app:` to `android:` see if that work for you

Comment: I'am using the onClick method in my fab, so i don't call the FAB. I tried it and it didn't work. The error is the same if i change app to android.

Comment: Then make sure that you use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`, also make sure that you use `AppComapt` Theme. Also, my bad, don't use `android:` use `app:`

Comment: Already using `AppCompatActivity`and the main Theme's parent is `parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`.

Comment: can you explain your xml. Why aren't you using RelativLayout directly instead of wrapping it in a Layout ?

Comment: Because i'm using [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html). _Data-binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of layout followed by a data element and a view root element._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by myself. I had to change the line

```
<declare-styleable name="FloatingActionButton">
```

to

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomFloatingActionButton">
```

Now everything is okay.

Comment: Awesome, man! You really made my day. I was looking for this months ago!